# Display Table-Cell not working in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, tablecell

I'm using `display:table-cell` to center content evenly on a page, and it works fine in every browser except Google Chrome, which is really weird!

The odd thing is that if I inspect element and manually add `display:block` to the parent, it fixes itself. Anyone know why this might be happening?

HTML

```
<section class="partner-brands wrapper">
    <h5><span>Proud Partners With</span></h5>
    <a href="./rewards"><img src="images/smart-trade-logo.svg" width="218" height="50" alt="Smart Trade"></a>
    <a href="http://www.collisionrepair.co.nz/" target="_blank"><img src="images/cra-logo.png" width="46" height="70" alt="Collision Repair Association"></a>
    <a href="http://www.busandcoach.co.nz/" target="_blank"><img src="images/baca-logo.svg" width="212" height="70" alt="Bus & Coach Association"></a>
    <a href="http://i-car.co.nz/" target="_blank"><img src="images/i-car-nz-logo.svg" width="162" height="70" alt="I-Car NZ"></a>
</section>
```

(S)CSS

```
.partner-brands {
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    h5 {
        position: relative; 
        text-align: center; 
        font-style: italic;
        margin-top: 0;
        &:before {
            content: "";
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            height: 0px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 10px;
            left: 0px;
            border-top: 1px solid #7D7D7D;
        }
        span {
            background: #FFFFFF;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            padding: 0 6px;
            position: relative;
            z-index: 2;
        }
    }
    a {
        display: table-cell;
        width: 250px;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
        -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
        -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
        -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
        transition: all 0.5s ease;
        &:hover {
            -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
            -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
            -o-transform: scale(1.1);
            -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
            transform: scale(1.1);
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
            -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
            box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        }
    }
}
```

FIREFOX SCREENSHOT
[image: Firefox Screenshot]

CHROME SCREENSHOT
[image: Google Chrome Screenshot]

Preview available at http://www.dbnz.co.nz/2016-preview/

If anyone could suggest a better way to do this that would be awesome as well. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have visited the page with both chrome and Firefox and all seems fine try restarting chrome to remove any cached stylesheet and see if it works. Also you might want to use incognito or developer mode to prevent caching if that's the case.

Comment: Really?? The 4 logos on the footer? I literally just installed Chrome on this computer to test it because the client alerted me it didn't work on his. :/

Comment: i had to try it again and both seem same to me here are the photos. could you indicate the difference. chrome: http://s10.postimg.org/rz0kgjodl/chrome.png and firefox: http://s28.postimg.org/4ewl3oux9/firefox.png

Comment: please see my screenshots? :) Were you attaching photos?

Comment: which version of chrome.

Comment: 46.0.2490.80 m. Not sure about my client though

Comment: Don't know what could be the issue coz mine also  46.0.2490.80 m.

Comment: I have just had an idea not brilliant but worth a shot, instead of displaying it as table data why not remove the display to leave it as inline then use padding and margin to set space in between.

Comment: Also could you run this code and post back screenshot of how it appears.    <table><tr>
    <td>row1a</td>
    <td>row1b</td> 
    <td>row1c</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>row2a</td>
    <td>row2b</td> 
    <td>row2c</td>
  </tr></table>

Comment: I'm wanting it to adapt on resize

Comment: that snippet displays as a table should. The odd thing is that I use this snippet in other places on the page, this is the only one not working.